# Will allowing light wallets to manually connect to server increase the risk of DDoS?

Tags: light-node, ddos

According to my knowledge, blockchains like Bitcoin and Ethereum provide great DDoS-resistant infrastructure since transactions are broadcasted to the network through random paths/nodes.

But since IOTA allows [manually assigning lightwallet servers](https://www.iotasupport.com/lightwallet.shtml), hackers can create malicious light nodes, point them to a particular server and raise tons of fake transactions in parallel to bring it down.

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

The light nodes still have to compute POW for every transaction they want to introduce into the network, which should be limiting the impact of DDoS quite a lot.

On the other hand, there are nodes which are configured not to require POW (they will perform it themselves instead), and these nodes are very susceptible to DDoS attacks.